# ConverterNotFoundException when trying return List from JPA Criteria Query

Tags: java, list, hibernate, jpa, type-conversion

I am writing a method to dynamically look up my Car entity in a database.
I decided on the JPA criteria Query, where I build predicate and use it to search the combined car and carDetails array.
In debug mode, I see that my query is ok and it returns me the appropriate entities.

**For example:**

> http://localhost:8180/car/find?color=black&brand=bmw&fuel=petrol

For this endpoint, the database should return a List with one car with the given values, and it does.
But when I want to return this list to the service, an error crashes:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
> converter found capable of converting from type
> [com.carRental.DemoCarRentalApp.car.carDetails.CarDetails] to type
> [com.carRental.DemoCarRentalApp.car.Car]

**REPOSITORY**: https://github.com/s0bieskii/CarRental/tree/experimental

**The query that hibernate sends:**

```
/* select
    distinct generatedAlias0 
from
    Car as generatedAlias1,
    CarDetails as generatedAlias2 
inner join
    generatedAlias1.carDetails as generatedAlias0 
where
    (
        generatedAlias1.brand=:param0 
    ) 
    and (
        (
            generatedAlias0.color=:param1 
        ) 
        and (
            generatedAlias0.fuel=:param2 
        ) 
    ) */ select
        distinct cardetails2_.id as id1_1_,
        cardetails2_.vin as vin2_1_,
        cardetails2_.average as average3_1_,
        cardetails2_.color as color4_1_,
        cardetails2_.doors as doors5_1_,
        cardetails2_.fuel as fuel6_1_,
        cardetails2_.inspection as inspecti7_1_,
        cardetails2_.insurance as insuranc8_1_,
        cardetails2_.mileage as mileage9_1_,
        cardetails2_.price as price10_1_,
        cardetails2_.registration_number as registr11_1_,
        cardetails2_.registration_year as registr12_1_,
        cardetails2_.seats as seats13_1_,
        cardetails2_.segment as segment14_1_,
        cardetails2_.transmission as transmi15_1_,
        cardetails2_.type as type16_1_ 
    from
        car car0_ cross 
    join
        car_details cardetails1_ 
    inner join
        car_details cardetails2_ 
            on car0_.fk_car_details_id=cardetails2_.id 
    where
        car0_.brand=? 
        and cardetails2_.color=? 
        and cardetails2_.fuel=?
```

**My dynamicSearch class code:**

```
package com.carRental.DemoCarRentalApp.car.repository;

import com.carRental.DemoCarRentalApp.car.Car;
import com.carRental.DemoCarRentalApp.car.carDetails.CarDetails;
import com.carRental.DemoCarRentalApp.car.carDetails.enums.Fuel;
import com.carRental.DemoCarRentalApp.car.carDetails.enums.Transmission;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.HibernateUtils;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.*;
import java.util.List;

public class CarFilterRepositoryImpl implements CarFilterRepository {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Car> search(Pageable pageable, String brand,
                            String model, Integer registrationYear, String segment, String color,
                            String fuel, String transmission, Integer doors, Integer seats, Double price,
                            Boolean available) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Car> cq = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
        Root<Car> car = cq.from(Car.class);


        Root<CarDetails> carDetails = cq.from(CarDetails.class);
        CarCriteriaBuilder carCriteriaBuilder = new CarCriteriaBuilder(car, cb);
        Join<CarDetails, Car> joinedCar=car.join("carDetails");
        CarDetailsCriteriaBuilder carDetailsCriteriaBuilder = new CarDetailsCriteriaBuilder(joinedCar, cb);
        
        carCriteriaBuilder.addCriteria("brand", brand)
                .addCriteria("model", model)
                .addCriteria("available", available);
        carDetailsCriteriaBuilder
                .addCriteria("registrationYear", registrationYear)
                .addCriteria("segment", segment)
                .addCriteria("color", color)
                .addCriteria("fuel", fuel)
                .addCriteria("transmission", transmission)
                .addCriteria("doors", doors)
                .addCriteria("seats", seats)
                .addCriteria("price", price);
        Predicate merged = cb.and(carCriteriaBuilder.getCriteria(), carDetailsCriteriaBuilder.gerCriteria());
        List<Car> carList=entityManager.createQuery(cq.select(joinedCar).where(merged).distinct(true)).getResultList();
       return carList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your typing is mixed up - you build a query stating it will be for 'car' but the select is on joinedCar which is a path to the car.carDetails/CarDetail objects. If you want cars back, use .select(car). Also note that you have an unneccessary/extra join in there because of the Root<CarDetails> carDetails = cq.from(CarDetails.class); that you seem to be able to just remove

Comment: @Chris as you can see i dont understand criteria query too well and there is probably something spelled wrong. Could you please help me fix this? I have two predicate, one refers to the Car entity and the other predicate refers to the Car details entity. How do I draw a car object after these predicate?

Comment: EDIT: When i change select(joinedCar) to select(car) i see another exception:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
:(

Comment: You have a very complex test environment with many moving parts - with multiple potential problems in it. You need to start smaller, as your InvalidDefinitionException is coming from Jackson - a tool used for JSON serialization, so might not be related to your JPA query. Check the exception stack trace and the message to find out exactly where it comes from, verify the model used for serialization to JSON, and maybe debug exactly what is returned and being used for that serialization.

Comment: @Chris stackTray said: https://pastebin.com/i8gLfUgn
I search many many thread in google but no idea what is going wrong with that :/

Comment: You pasted the original org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException, which is because the query originally posted is selecting (and so returning) CarDetails when the method and query signature expect it to return Car instances. I have the solution to that, which is to select the cars you want to return. you should post a new question for the InvalidDefinitionException as I suspect it has to do with your REST setup and the car model used for JSON serialization, but I can only guess.